# seamless-immutable converting my Object to Hash

Tags: reactjs, seamless-immutable

I am using react+ redux with immutable js. I would like to store an object in the state:

```
mainFilesUploader = FileUploader({ fileCredentials: action.fileCredentials }, fileUploadType.mainFiles)
formState = formState.set('fileUploaders', {
  mainFiles: mainFilesUploader,
})
```

Before being put in state the object looks something like this:

```
FineUploaderS3 {options: {…}, methods: qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic, qq: ƒ}
```

However at the end of the state... it's just a plain hash:

```
{options: {…}, methods: {…}, qq: ƒ, merge: ƒ, replace: ƒ, …}
```

Is there a way I can stop this stupid conversion? Why does it convert my object ?